# I need help to convert numbers to words

Tags: javascript, string, input, onclick, numbers

I need to change numbers to a words like 1=A,2=B. When I type into input something like `12` the result should be `AB` if type only `2` result must be `B` inside P tag.

```
<input type="text" id="nums">
<button id="btn"></button>
<p id="words"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

    script here...

</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="nums">
        <button id="btn" onclick="run()">run</button>
        <p id="words"></p>
        <script>
        function run(){

            var alfa='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
            var alfa_array = alfa.split(""); //this creates an array which contain whole characters 
            var num=document.getElementById("nums").value;
            var number_array = num.split(""); //this creates an array which contain whole numbers in input

//then you can go through each number inside number_array and use that number as key in alfa_array.this gives you matching character for each number.then join all characters together.

            var result='';
            for(var i in number_array){            
            result+=alfa_array[parseInt(number_array[i])-1];
            }

        document.getElementById("words").html=result;
        }
        </script>
```

this will do the job.

Comment: please explain the reason to downvote this .https://jsfiddle.net/kmwdh9bj/ it works properly

Comment: It was probably downvoted because you only posted code without any explanation.

Comment: Äsiri, it is not too late to improve this post. Consider adding some paragraph text _in the answer itself_ to explain what your approach was to solving this problem. This could be useful to future readers.

Comment: ok.. thanks for inform me. comments added to explain each steps.

Comment: appreciate if you can mark this answer as correct answer